# Porting C source code to Delphi

Tags: c, delphi

Presently I am trying to port an encryption library written in C to Delphi. It is almost finished, however the C source code consists of the following instructions that I have not been able to cope with so far.

```c
unsigned char one_block[16];
unsigned char * iv
((unsigned int *)one_block)[3] = ((unsigned int *) iv)[3];
```

...

I tried to convert it even as

```delphi
var
  one_block: Array[0..15] of Byte;
  iv : PByte;
begin
  PDWord(one_block[3]):= PDWord(iv[3]);
  ...
end;
```

but it obviously fails to compile, because the left side of the expression cannot be assigned.

Can anyone with more practice in porting give me a hint on how to solve this problem?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You've used `one_block` in both of your code snippets, with no indication of what it might be. You've also not assigned any value to `iv` before trying to access `iv[3]`. It's pretty difficult to try to port code when you haven't included the major parts.

Comment: Sorry Ken. You absolutely are right. They are mistyping in both cases. 'one_block' should have been 'block' as in the declaration parts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
{$POINTERMATH ON}
PCardinal(@one_block)[3] := PCardinal(iv)[3]; // fills bytes 12..15 of one_block
```

As the comments say, I assume that the C code somehow initializes `iv`, and also sets the other parts of `one_block`. You did not show that.

Now, if your version of Delphi does not support `$POINTERMATH`, you'll have to do:

```
type
  PCardinalArray = ^TCardinalArray;
  TCardinalArray = array[0..3] of Cardinal;

  ...

  PCardinalArray(@one_block)^[3] := PCardinalArray(iv)^[3];
```

Comment: This one seems to work at first glace but I need to check the whole procedure.

Comment: It should work. But if you like it, don't hesitate to upvote it.

Comment: Note that, as I commented, `PCardinal(@x)^[3]` accesses `x` as if it were an array of Cardinals (or DWORDs), so its sets the third Cardinal, or bytes 12..15 of the array.

Comment: FWIW, my obligatory recommendation: [Addressing pointers](http://www.rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-pointers.html).

Comment: My only suggestion is to not use `PCardinal`, since it is a generic type that could change size in a future release (it already has once before). `PDWord` or `PUint32` is more appropriate and matches the C code.

Comment: @Remy: you are right, but the original code used `unsigned int`, which I (IMO correctly) translated with `Cardinal`. I agree that a `UInt32` or `LongWord` would be better, also in the original C code (`uint32_t`).

Answer (score 1):

```
PDWord(one_block)[3] := PDWord(iv)[3];
```

...if Pascal/Delphi can use PDWord as array.
1. Cast (change type of the array).
2. Acces the array (of ints/dwords).

EDIT:

Well, IV and BLOCK should be used as

```
array[0..3] of Integer (or DWord)
```

...as it seems you are using AES-128

so, you should declare

```
TBlock = array[0..3] of Integer/Dword
PBlock = ^TBlock
```

and cast it this way

```
PBlock(@block)^[3] = PBlock(@iv)^[3]
```

or maybe directly

```
TBlock(block)[3] = TBlock(iv)[3]
```

...I am sorry but it has been 10 years I was working with Delphi

Comment: Thank you, but I already tried this solution without success. In Delphi, the left side of an expression like this can't be assigned to.

Comment: try casting to ^array of integers - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508783/how-to-cast-an-array-to-pointer-and-back-in-delphi

Comment: Not quite correct. `iv` is already a pointer, so should not be referenced: `PBlock(@one_block)^[3] := PBlock(iv)^[3];`. That was my solution too. <g>